# Why is my div resizing?

Tags: html, css

My header is structured as a table. I finally managed to make it so that the last li is floated to the right and X % to the left while still being compatible with different screen sizes. However, my 'profile picture' div is resizing and resembles a squished circle as a result. How do I make sure that the div is always 40px in width and height (if this is the right way to go around it)?

[image]

CSS

```
#hdr-profile {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    display: flex; 
    margin-left: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#hdr-profile-pic {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: white url("https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/11760274_1109394289087955_3712628479579288500_n.jpg?oh=ff64d9b1a44338d53d414459ff92aa71&oe=574558FA") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
    <li>
        <div id="hdr-profile">
            <div id="hdr-profile-pic" title="My Profile">
                <div id="hdr-profile-country" title="Liam is in Spain"></div>
            </div>
            <span id="hdr-profile-name" class="select"><a href="#">Liam Macmillan</a></span>
            <i class="material-icons md-26 icn-lft icn-hvr">arrow_drop_down</i>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/uxdLexs8/1/?

Comment: Perfect! flex: 0 0 40px; solved it. Want to add this as an answer?

Comment: Nah, glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to add a !important after the 40px in your css of the profile picture

Comment: Doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because of the size of the drop-down. In the JSFiddle that Nenad Vracar linked, the picture comes in totally fine. Don't use !important to force the size, it's bad practice and causes unexpected behavior. Instead, try experimenting with the size of the dropdown. I don't have the rest of your code, or I'd have looked into it.

Comment: As a starter, I'd say look in properties of the element(in Chrome, below the box model). Track down `width: ` and check the value. I'm sure it'll be less than 40px, or something like that. Then track down the rule that sets that and delete it.